# How to get arbitrary alignment of array in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

This code does not give the correct alignment:

```
alignas(4096) int* p = new int[1024];
printf(“%x”, p);
```

This should print

```
0x......000
```

with three zeros at the end. I can’t get it to work. Is this even possible?

Comment: Try [aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc). The `new` operator doesn't know that you are going to store the result into a pointer that requires nonstandard alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is aligning the *pointer* `int*` to be aligned to a `4096` byte boundary. What you want to do is align the memory allocated by `new` to be aligned to the boundary.

The only *standard* way to do this is with C++17 or above, using either [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) with the `std::aligned_val_t` argument, or [`std::aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc). E.g:

```cpp
int* p = new(std::align_val_t{4096}) int[1024];
...
delete [] p;

// or a more C-style way
int* p = static_cast<int*>(std::aligned_alloc(4096, sizeof(int)*1024));
...
std::free(p);
```

Here's a working example using GCC on [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZUGt4N); and the same example failing with MSVC is [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6sfzf95MP).

---

If you aren't using C++17, you will be required to use OS-specific alignment-allocating functions, such as [`posix_memalign`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) for POSIX-compliant operating systems, or [`_aligned_malloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019) on Windows.

Alternatively, if your system has C11 headers installed, you can make use of the C-standard [`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) defined in `<stdlib.h>`. This is the same as the `std::aligned_alloc` equivalent, except the `std::` namespace qualified one is only guaranteed to be made available with C++17 or above.

---

**Edit:** It seems that MSVC does not allow the first-form using `operator new` due to what they perceive to be an ambiguity in the standard (see the comment section [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/528320/using-c17-new-stdalign-val-tn-syntax-results-in-er.html) for more detail). If you are working with MSVC, or are looking for the most portable code -- you should make use `std::aligned_alloc` instead.

Comment: I now get an error that I have To use the same equivalent form for delete

Comment: I've updated to add a note. It appears that MSVC yields an error for over-aligned `new` due to what they perceive to be an ambiguity in the standard. Since your question is tagged `visual studio`, you will probably need to use `aligned_alloc` instead

Comment: The `/Zc:sizedDealloc-` option can help in an emergency (note the minus symbol at the end). [This Compiler Explorer example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5Mqdar5xE) has the option enabled.